# Visio gradient fill and stencils

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am trying to save a simple rectangle with a gradient fill to a stencil in Vision (2016), but the gradient won't seem to save.

In fact, it seems somewhat arbitrary which formattings do get saved.

See below:
[image: visio: original shapes vs stencil]

Both shapes are just rectangles with formatting (background gradients and/or beveling) - nothing else. The shapes labeled "original" are what I drew. I then dragged those onto a stencil, and dragged them back onto the sheet.

Both seem to have retained the shadowing. The top shape lost its gradient, while the bottom shape did not - but it did lose its 3D beveling.

What I have tried:

1. This is all done in a theme-less design. I used the "Blank Drawing" template, and no theme was  applied.
2. I have tried protecting the shapes prior to adding them to the stencil. I went to Developer -> Protection, and selected everything short of being able to select and move the shape.

The only thing I could think of was that perhaps there is some limitation to the number of allowable gradient stops (I have quite a few), but that would be crazy - and the loss of beveling makes me think something else is going on.

[image: gradient stops for top shape]

Comment: Which format did you save as? .vss? .vssx?

Comment: @PaulHerber Hmm.. that's a good point/question. Many of my stencils are so old they are .vss.. And this was one. I'll try it with a .vssx.

Comment: @PaulHerber Aha!! That was it. Thank you!

Comment: @PaulHerber (ps. you should probably make it an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The older .vss format does not store gradient fill information, you need to use the newer .vssx format.